# Generate dynamically Select with Optgroup with Bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, bootstrap-select

I'm looking for help with this. I have this function to get all the employees of my app.

```
function listar_empleados() {
        funcion = "listar_empleados";
        
        $.post("/bureau-veritas/Controllers/EmpleadosController.php", { funcion }, (response) => {
            const employees = JSON.parse(response);
        
            /* Group employees by department */
            let employeeGroups = {};
            employees.forEach((employee) => {
                if (!employeeGroups[employee.departamento]) {
                    employeeGroups[employee.departamento] = [];
                }
                employeeGroups[employee.departamento].push(employee);
            });
            
            console.log(employeeGroups);
            /* Generate HTML template */
            let template = '';
            for (let departamento in employeeGroups) {
                template += `<optgroup label="${departamento}">`;
                employeeGroups[departamento].sort((a, b) => (a.nombre > b.nombre) ? 1 : -1)
                    .forEach((employee) => {
                        template += `<option value="${employee.rfc}" data-subtext="${employee.rol}">${employee.nombre} ${employee.apellidos}</option>`;
                    });
                template += '</optgroup>';
            }
            $('#crearcontrato_encargado_suplente').html(template).selectpicker('refresh');
        });
        
      }
```

When the request is done, I get an object like this where all employees are grouped by their department. The keys are:

- rfc -> it's the primary key of each employee
- nombre -> name
- apellidos -> last names
- departamento -> the department where the employee has been assign
- role -> the role or title of the employee in their departments
- estado -> boolean for knowing if an employee is active or not

```
{
    "Contabilidad": [
        {
            "rfc": "CENAWELIO2023",
            "nombre": "Jonathan",
            "apellidos": "Martinez",
            "departamento": "Contabilidad",
            "rol": "Jefe de departamento",
            "estado": "1"
        }
    ],
    "Industria": [
        {
            "rfc": "FEESHAMOR2023",
            "nombre": "Francisco",
            "apellidos": "Cerino",
            "departamento": "Industria",
            "rol": "Representante Técnico",
            "estado": "1"
        },
        {
            "rfc": "JORGE-ARPAIZ",
            "nombre": "Jorge",
            "apellidos": "Arpaiz Herrera",
            "departamento": "Industria",
            "rol": "Representante Técnico",
            "estado": "1"
        },
        {
            "rfc": "MIGUELNARANJO",
            "nombre": "Miguel Ángel",
            "apellidos": "Naranjo",
            "departamento": "Industria",
            "rol": "Jefe de departamento",
            "estado": "1"
        },
        {
            "rfc": "QUMO0009066E3",
            "nombre": "Oscar",
            "apellidos": "Quevedo",
            "departamento": "Industria",
            "rol": "Auxiliar de departamento",
            "estado": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see, the object is fine, but the trouble comes when it's time to print the template.

[I don't know why the template is printing like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpZFi.png)

I've done console.log(template) already to be sure of it's generating properly, and it does, but the template I get it's the same, and only one, employee on different departaments. In the pic it seems the departments are been showing as well.

What I am expecting to get it's a template like this, but the header of groups showing the department title with their employees with each employee role.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSCGw.png)

Hope anyone can help me. ^^